# Null terminator + String matching using Firebird C API and parameterized inserts

Tags: firebird

I have several VARCHAR columns. After performing inserts using a parameterized statement, I would like to query one of them, e.g., `select * from my_table where name = 'my_varchar'`.

This works properly if I insert my char arrays with `sqllen=strlen(my_char_array)`. However, the strings are then not null terminated upon reading. I can add a null terminator at sqllen, but then my strings will all be the maximum size of varchar. If I set `sqllen=strlen(my_char_array)+1`, the strings have the proper null terminators for reading, but the select statement fails (nothing matches 'max' because of this added character). It works with the added null terminators if I do `select * from my_table where name like 'my_varchar%'`, but this seems like a rather inelegant solution.

Is there a way to get properly null terminated strings while still allowing the exact equality string searching to work properly? I have a feeling I am missing something pretty simple and would be grateful of any advice!

Comment: I think this is a question that is better asked on the firebird-support list, it is my experience that not many people familiar with the low-level native API of Firebird are available on Stack Overflow. That said, for Stack Overflow, please make sure your question include a [mre] demonstrating what you're currently doing, and the problem you have with it. Especially the content of sqldata is important, because varchar values are prefixed with 2 bytes with the actual length (in bytes).

Comment: As far as I know, you need to set sqllen to the actual length of the data, and for varchar, make sure that the first 2 bytes of sqldata are also the actual length (little endian), so to store a 'x' in a varchar(50) field, sqllen = 1, sqldata =0x01007800 (null terminator); if your sqldata is longer than the minimum necessary for this value (2 bytes length, 1 byte value, 1 byte null terminator), they should be zero-filled I think.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get or use null-terminated strings in Firebird API.

SQL_TEXT is a fixed-length array of characters.
SQL_VARYING is a param_vary structure with length and again fixed-length array of characters without any special termination.

Comment: You can store null-terminated string in a SQLVAR if you want to, it just doesn't matter compared to storing something that is not null-terminated.

Comment: Technically SQLVAR doesn't store data just a pointer to a buffer which content is interpreted according to the value of sqltype and other SQLVAR fields. You can store in this buffer anything beyond of expected data and these extras will be simply ignored. But I don't think that this is what @mlawsonca has on mind.

Answer (score 1):

My strings weren't being properly sized because of an error in how I was specifying the varchar length in the first two bytes. When I followed the SQL_VARYING examples included with Firebird (generating a struct with a short and a char[], and passing a pointer to this structure as sqldata), the strings were properly sized without the null terminator.

Comment: you perhaps has also to account for units of measure. The same data can be measured in characters and in bytes, which, in different charsets (ASCII, UTF-16/UCS2, UTF-8, others) correspond differently. I expect Firebird low-level API to mean bytes length, while your `strlen` would count characters instead. Sometimes it is the same result, sometimes not.

Comment: strlen() always counts bytes.